# How to capture wrist gestures in a Wear OS app?

Tags: java, android-studio, wear-os

I would like to see a simple, complete Android Studio Wear OS Java app source code that handles Wear OS wrist gestures.  I have reviewed the guidance at [Text](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/user-input/wrist-gestures), but would like to see a complete example including java source code, xml, and manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Demo Code for the wrist gestures.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.appname;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.activity.WearableActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends WearableActivity {

    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextView = findViewById(R.id.text);

        // Enables wrist gestures
        setAmbientEnabled();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // Wrist flick gesture
            if (ev.getEdgeFlags() == MotionEvent.EDGE_WRIGHT) {
                Log.d("Wrist Gesture", "Flick wrist right");
                mTextView.setText("Flicked wrist right");
                return true;
            } else if (ev.getEdgeFlags() == MotionEvent.EDGE_LEFT) {
                // Wrist tilt gesture
                Log.d("Wrist Gesture", "Tilt wrist left");
                mTextView.setText("Tilted wrist left");
                return true;
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:layout_box="all">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.appname">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Wearable">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.wearable.action.WEARABLE_ACTIVITY" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.appname"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        // Enabling multidex support for the app.
        multiDexEnabled true

        // Enabling standalone mode for Wear OS apps.
        wearAppUnbundled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.1.0'
    // Adding multidex support.
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

You can also use the following code to capture wrist gestures:

```
 final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                if (event1.getY() - event2.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 100) {
                    // Handle up gesture
                    return true;
                } else if (event2.getY() - event1.getY() > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 100) {
                    // Handle down gesture
                    return true;
                }

                return super.onFling(event1, event2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }
        });
```

Comment: could you please add the build.gradle (:app) file to your answer?  Thank you!

Comment: I have added the build.gradle in my answer

Comment: I have entered your code and successfully loaded it onto my Fossil Gen 6  watch.  Though the code executed, it did not recognize wrist gestures.  I contacted Fossil customer support, and after several back-and-forths, I got the following response:    
I double-checked everything again and found that Wrist gesture is not yet available on Wear OS 3. You can rest assured that I have already passed along your feedback to the engineering team regarding the wrist gestures for further consideration. Please stay tuned and wait for our new releases!

Comment: You can also try the code for gestures that I posted above (UPDATED CODE ABOVE).